# How to pass a object into a directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a `items` array which is used by ng-repeat to render the menu,
and on click of `Add to cart` button `addItem()` is called.

Currently i pass the name of the selected item as the `name` attribute in `item-container` directive.
How shall i pass an entire object through the attribute to the `directive`

**HTML snippet**

```
<p ng-repeat = "item in items">
<item-container
    startcounter = 1 
    resetter     = 'reset'
    item = 'item'
    name         = {{item.name}} >
    {{item.name}}
</item-container><br><br>
</p>
```

**JS snippet**

```
.directive('itemCounter',function(){
return {
controller: function() {return {}},
    restrict:'E',
    scope:{
  item:"=",
  resetter:"="
    },
transclude:true,
    link:function(scope,elem,attr){

        scope.qty = attr.startcounter
        scope.add = function(){

            scope.qty++;
        }
        scope.remove = function(){
            scope.qty--;
        }
        scope.addItem = function(){
            console.log(attr.item);
            scope.$parent.addMsg(scope.qty,attr.name)
            console.log("value when submitted:" + scope.qty + "name:"+ attr.name);
            scope.qty = attr.startcounter;
            scope.$parent.resettrigger();
        }

        scope.$watch(function(attr){
            return attr.resetter
        },
        function(newValue){
            if(newValue === true){
                scope.qty = attr.startcounter;
            }
        });


    },
    template:"<button ng-click='addItem();'>Add to cart</button>&nbsp&nbsp"+            
         "<button ng-click='remove();' >-</button>&nbsp"+
                 "{{qty}}&nbsp" +
                 "<button ng-click='add();'>+</button>&nbsp&nbsp"+
         "<a ng-transclude> </a>"


}
```

Answer (score 1):

Currently you actually aren't even passing in the `name` it seems. All the passing in magic happens in this part:

```
scope:{
  resetter:"="
},
```

As you can see, there is no mention of `name`. What you need to do is add a field for `item` and just pass that in:

```
scope:{
  resetter:"=",
  item: "="
},
```

Then you can just do

```
<p ng-repeat = "item in items">
<item-container
    startcounter = 1 
    resetter     = 'reset'
    item         = item >
    {{item.name}}
</item-container><br><br>
</p>
```

Also I'm fairly sure you dont want to be using `transclude` here. Look into `templateUrl`

Comment: i have edited the code to include the passing of  the object. but when i console it, it is printing as `item`.Am i  passing the object in the right manner

Comment: @dreamer Your current code should produce a syntax error (you are missing a `,`), but besides that please don't recycle the same question for multiple questions. If you have a new question, please ask a new one.

Comment: i am able to access the object using `scope.item` and not with `attr.item`